# Flatbuffers: how do you build nested tables?

Tags: java, flatbuffers

I have a 3-level nested Java POJO that looks like this in the schema file:

```
struct FPathSegment {
    originIata:ushort;
    destinationIata:ushort;
}

table FPathConnection {
    segments:[FPathSegment]; 
}   

table FPath {
    connections:[FPathConnection];
}
```

When I try to serialize a Java POJO to the Flatbuffer equivalent I pretty much get "nested serialzation is not allowed" error every time I try to use a common FlatBufferBuilder to build this entire object graph.

There is no clue in the docs to state if I have a single builder for the entire graph? A separate one for every table/struct? If separate, how do you import the child objects into the parent?

There are all these methods like create/start/add various vectors, but no explanation what builders go in there. Painfully complicated.

Here is my Java code where I attempt to serialize my Java POJO into Flatbuffers equivalent:

```
private FPath convert(Path path) {
    FlatBufferBuilder bld = new FlatBufferBuilder(1024);

    // build the Flatbuffer object
    FPath.startFPath(bld);
    FPath.startConnectionsVector(bld, path.getConnections().size());

    for(Path.PathConnection connection : path.getConnections()) {

        FPathConnection.startFPathConnection(bld);

        for(Path.PathSegment segment : connection.getSegments()) {
            FPathSegment.createFPathSegment(bld,
                    stringCache.getPointer(segment.getOriginIata()),
                    stringCache.getPointer(segment.getDestinationIata()));
        }

        FPathConnection.endFPathConnection(bld);
    }

    FPath.endFPath(bld);
    return FPath.getRootAsFPath(bld.dataBuffer());
}
```

Every start() method throws a "FlatBuffers: object serialization must not be nested" exception, can't figure out what is the way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You use a single `FlatBufferBuilder`, but you must finish serializing children before starting the parents.

In your case, that requires you to move `FPath.startFPath` to the end, and `FPath.startConnectionsVector` to just before that. This means you need to store the offsets for each `FPathConnection` in a temp array.

This will make the nesting error go away.

The reason for this inconvenience is to allow the serialization process to proceed without any temporary data structures.